# Bitcoin API standard

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I'm trying to implement a bitcoin full node while learning a new programming language, but I can't find the full set of public API that the full node has to expose. I assume the standard will be bitcoin core, but then again the closest I can get is the https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference . Where should I start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this github page about btcd, one of the concurrent of bitcoin core where they talk about their API which is fully compatible with bitcoin

> btcd provides a JSON-RPC API that is fully compatible with the original bitcoind/bitcoin-qt. There are a few key differences between btcd and bitcoind as far as how RPCs are serviced:

https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/master/docs/json_rpc_api.md